# Inserting caption on an algorithm in Beamer

Tags: beamer, floats, algorithms

I am trying to insert the caption on an algorithm in `beamer` presentation. The algorithm syntax is correct and it is working while using `\documentclass{article}` but it shows following error when `\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}` is used:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

Below is the sample code:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} %comment \begin{frame} and \end{frame} while using article
    \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{This is comment}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \ForAll{$point$ ~in $trajectory$}
        \State {$i\gets maxval$}
        \Do
        \State $success \gets dist(a,b)$
        \doWhile{$success \le 0$}
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Below are the TeX compiler details:

```
pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.5.18)
```

Comment: btw, you're loading `algpseudocode` twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical behaviour of floats are naturally suppressed within a presentation, as it doesn't have the same flow as an article. So, under [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer), `figure`s and `table`s may be structured in a similar way they're done under [`article`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co), but `beamer` just puts them in the `frame` you use them, rather than finding "a suitable location" through floating.

When you use an `algorithm`, it hasn't been formatted to *not float*, which is the root of the problem. Luckily, [`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm) defines its floating `algorithm` environment using [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) which, in turn, defines the non-floating specifier `[H]`. Use this to keep `beamer` happy:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%
\algnewcommand{\var}{\textit}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]% <-------- do not float, stay right [H]ERE!
    \caption{This is comment}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \ForAll{\var{point} in \var{trajectory}}
        \State {$i \gets \var{maxval}$}
        \Do
          \State $\var{success} \gets dist(a,b)$
        \doWhile{$\var{success} \leq 0$}
      \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that `[H]` is completely different from `[h]` or `[h!]`. The former actually sets a `minipage` while making `\caption` think its in a float (since `\caption`s are usually associated with a float), while the latter still sets a float that *could* move. As an FAQ in this regard, see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I appreciate it.